# Repeated reciprocal

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, recursion, rational-numbers

What you need to do is create a function/program that takes a decimal as input, and outputs the result of repeatedly taking the reciprocal of the fractional part of the number, until the number becomes an integer.

More specifically, the process is as follows:

1. Let x be the input
2. If x is an integer, output it.
3. Otherwise: \$x \leftarrow \frac{1}{\mathrm{frac}(x)}\$. Go back to 2.

\$\mathrm{frac}(x)\$ is the fractional component of \$x\$, and equals \$x - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor\$. \$\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor\$ is the floor of x, which is the greatest integer less than \$x\$.

Test cases:

```
0 = 0
0.1 = 1/10 -> 10
0.2 = 1/5 -> 5
0.3 = 3/10 -> 10/3 -> 1/3 -> 3
0.4 = 2/5 -> 5/2 -> 1/2 -> 2
0.5 = 1/2 -> 2
0.6 = 3/5 -> 5/3 -> 2/3 -> 3/2 -> 1/2 -> 2
0.7 = 7/10 -> 10/7 -> 3/7 -> 7/3 -> 1/3 -> 3
0.8 = 4/5 -> 5/4 -> 1/4 -> 4
0.9 = 9/10 -> 10/9 -> 1/9 -> 9
1 = 1
3.14 = 157/50 -> 7/50 -> 50/7 -> 1/7 -> 7
6.28 = 157/25 -> 7/25 -> 25/7 -> 4/7 -> 7/4 -> 3/4 -> 4/3 -> 1/3 -> 3
```

Summary for 0 to 1 at increments of 0.1: 0, 10, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 9, 1

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins.

Clarifications:

- "Bonus points" for no round-off error
- Should work for any non-negative rational number (ignoring round-off error)
- You can, but don't have to output the steps taken
- You can take input as a decimal, fraction, or pair of numbers, which can be in a string.

Sorry for all the issues, this is my first question on this website.

Comment: The fact that this terminates is closely related to the possibility of expressing a decimal in continued fraction.

Comment: Are we expected to output floats? They cause some precision issue.

Comment: Could you detail the process a little bit more?  I'm unsure as to what "reciprocal of the fractional part of the number" entails, and the test cases don't help much either

Comment: Can we take two integers as input to represent a rational number?

Comment: I thought you need to output the numbers in the process as well.

Comment: Optionally. You can, but don't have to.

Comment: This is equal to the final element of the simple continued fraction of the input.

Comment: Are the test cases the only input we need to be able to handle?

Comment: @Shaggy No.These are just examples. If you encounter round-off error, you can post the version with round-off error and the fixed version together.

Comment: Please add more test cases, so, for numbers with more than one decimal place and numbers greater than 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## J, 18 bytes

```
%@(-<.)^:(~:<.)^:_
```

In J, the idiom `u ^: v ^:_` means "Keep applying the verb `u` while condition `v` returns true.

In our case, the ending condition is defined by the hook `~:<.`, which means "the floor of the number `<.` is not equal `~:` to the number itself" -- so we'll stop when the main verb `u` returns an int.

`u` in this case is another hook `-<.` -- the number minus its floor -- whose return value is fed into `@` the reciprocal verb `%`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcnBCkBAFIXh/TzFSQnFNGMIN1OehIVMsrGw5tWHXLOxOP19nc27A5ag8MzHQ1r0Mhspvejt5DMRSSTOUoIcJ8EdQizzuqMCLByUbNlafdbsOvwl2wSbnxt2F9yxG7aRuvI3)

Comment: Also 18, but has some floating point imprecisions because of tolerances presumably: `_2{(%@-<.) ::]^:a:`.

Comment: `%@|~&1^:(~:<.)^:_`

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 36 bytes

```mathematica
Last@*ContinuedFraction@*Rationalize
```

#### Demo

```mathematica
In[1]:= f = Last@*ContinuedFraction@*Rationalize

Out[1]= Last @* ContinuedFraction @* Rationalize

In[2]:= f[0]

Out[2]= 0

In[3]:= f[0.1]

Out[3]= 10

In[4]:= f[0.2]

Out[4]= 5

In[5]:= f[0.3]

Out[5]= 3

In[6]:= f[0.4]

Out[6]= 2

In[7]:= f[0.5]

Out[7]= 2

In[8]:= f[0.6]

Out[8]= 2

In[9]:= f[0.7]

Out[9]= 3

In[10]:= f[0.8]

Out[10]= 4

In[11]:= f[0.9]

Out[11]= 9

In[12]:= f[1]

Out[12]= 1
```

Comment: What happens without `Rationalize`?

Comment: @GregMartin Without `Rationalize`, Mathematica thinks there isn’t sufficient precision to generate all terms of the continued fraction. For example, `ContinuedFraction[0.1]` is just `{0}`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 101 bytes

```python
lambda s:g(int(s.replace(".","")),10**s[::-1].index("."))
g=lambda a,b:a and(b%a and g(b%a,a)or b//a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7NDsIgDAfwu09BSExgQTbc/CLZk6gHEIZLJiNsB316lMWD9tL2l@bfNLzm@@jr1LWXNKiHNgpN0pHez2Ti0YZB3SzBHDOMKWWiKorpLOVGXHnvjX3mFaUr136zimn5qd4QvV46cnliio4R6bJUNIWYj3cEV7zK2R8L4C1wDdwA74D3wAfgI/Dpz2L5L70B)

Format: the string must contain a decimal point.

Comment: `.replace(".","")` -> `.replace(*"._")` save 1 byte

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 42 bytes

```
{($_,{1/($_-.floor)}...*.nude[1]==1)[*-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WkMlXqfaUB9I6eql5eTnF2nW6unpaenllaakRhvG2toaakZr6RrG1v63VihOrFRIA6rUNzTQVEjLL1Iw1NMzNPgPAA)

The `nude` method returns the **nu**merator and **de**nominator of a rational number as a two-element list.  It's shorter to get the denominator this way than to call the `denominator` method directly.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 69 bytes

```php
for(;round(1e9*$a=&$argn)/1e9!=$o=round($a);)$a=1/($a-($a^0));echo$o;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpNCsIwEIX3vYVhkI7FNgE3ZTp4kSIErSabTAi6kp49Tu3i/fG9HHKdrjnkBnx5JTa2vxhqnlJaiGwJ4sROvWPbO/zuJ4hUtwcV@aRH65bxBJ6Pf4iDzgOD8A7BI6FSN2g9q24WkZZ7EBCqW5r5DXFOhtb6Aw)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 146 bytes

```php
for($f=.1;(0^$a=$argn*$f*=10)!=$a;);for(;1<$f;)($x=($m=max($a,$f))%$n=min($a,$f))?[$f=$n,$a=$x]:$f=!!$a=$m/$n;echo($o=max($a,$f))>1?$o:min($a,$f);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLCsIwFET3/kXLCDel1AZ3vb3mQ0QhiDEu8qCr/H3aCqK7OczMyT7X2WSfD7DLK0o7DueWq0sLwcmgmcY7rHzKDq4TPapmQ1a8b1jPcKwIRQhBgi0E28MpdUSU8I5fNNdNh9jvrnKbNmiaPYcTIj8fPhHS//2iDdL0E3CtKw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 47 bytes

This beats [Wheat Wizard's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152377/71256) because `GHC.Real` allows us to pattern match on rationals using `:%`, aswell as having a shorter name

```hs
import GHC.Real
f(x:%1)=x
f x=f$1/(x-floor x%1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMHdw1kvKDUxhytNo8JK1VDTtoIrTaHCNk3FUF@jQjctJz@/SKECKP4/NzEzz7agKDOvRCVNwVjP0OQ/AA)

`f` takes a `Rational` number as input, although ghc allows them to be written in a decimal format, within a certain precision.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>40</s> 34 bytes

Edit:

- -6 bytes: @WheatWizard pointed out the fraction can probably be given as two separate arguments.

(Couldn't resist posting this after seeing Haskell answers with verbose imports – now I see some other language answers are also essentially using this method.)

`!` takes two integer arguments (numerator and denominator of the fraction; they don't need to be in smallest terms but the denominator must be positive) and returns an integer. Call as `314!100`.

```hs
n!d|m<-mod n d,m>0=d!m|0<1=div n d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxNCoMwEIbhfU8RpYuEqCS1v6CepJtgAgbNGKK2FLx7Wjuuno@Bdzo19WYYolMWaguzCaqdjwsMFsxUOOXp0@eN5zwleUNSzqdufFO6QLuE8KEJYzQYpYlnjBX/KEKiV1flbtQEiM5cI2qduFVUstb2td1ipCKTgh2oRE5IiZyRC3JFbsgdeez5/qaUW/NbXw)

- Ignoring type mismatch, the fractional part of `n/d` (assuming `d` positive) is `mod n d/d`, so unless `mod n d==0`, `!` recurses with a representation of `d/mod n d`.

Comment: [34 bytes?  I don't know why you are using such a cumbersome IO method](https://tio.run/##LcxNCoMwEIbhfU8RpYuEqCS1v6CepJtgAgbNGKK2FLx7Wjuuno@Bdzo19WYYolMWaguzCaqdjwsMFsxUOOXp0@eN5zwleUNSzqdufFO6QLuE8KEJYzQYpYlnjBX/KEKiV1flbtQEiM5cI2qduFVUstb2td1ipCKTgh2oRE5IiZyRC3JFbsgdeez5/qaUW/NbXw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @WheatWizard Hm well, I interpreted "pair" as having to be a pair rather than two distinct arguments. I suppose that's an overly Haskell-centric interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
®İ$%1$©¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QuiMbVFQNVQ6tPLT/////BnqGAA)

Floating-point inaccuracies.

Comment: Good luck doing it for 0.7

Comment: @LeakyNun That luck means either infinite loops or infinite loops...

Comment: [Use `M` to fix floating-point inaccuracies :P](https://tio.run/##y/3//9C6IxtUVA1VDq08tP////8GeoYA). It's Jelly but with arbitrary precision mathematics. Doesn't fix the 0.7 loop though.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino M is way outdated version of Jelly.

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///IBlVDlUP7////b6BnCAA)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing The thing is that you have to do it on the fractional part though. (yes, the code is kinda messy, given that the first `$` should be a `¤` instead :p)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), 67 bytes

```python
from sympy import*
k=Rational(input())
while k%1:k=1/(k%1)
print(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehuDK3oFIhM7cgv6hEiyvbNiixJDM/LzFHIzOvoLREQ1OTqzwjMydVIVvV0Crb1lBfA8jQ5Cooyswr0cjW/P/fQM8cAA)

Sympy is a symbolic mathematics package for Python. Because it is symbolic and not binary, there are no floating point inaccuracies.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 25 bytes

```
f=(a,b)=>a%b?f(b,a%b):a/b
```

Call `f(a,b)` for `a/b`

Comment: If `gcd(a,b)=1` can remove `/b`

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>62</s> 61 bytes

```hs
import Data.Ratio
f x|denominator x==1=x|u<-x-floor x%1=f$1/u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRLyixJDOfK02hoiYlNS8/NzMvsSS/SKHC1tbQtqKm1Ea3QjctJx8kompom6ZiqF/6PzcxM8@2oCgzr0QlTcPY0ETV0MBA8z8A)

Uses Haskell's `Data.Ratio` library for arbitrary precision rationals.  If only the builtin names were not so long.

Comment: @H.PWiz Nice! I had been trying to pattern match with `Data.Ratio`. I've never heard of `GHC.Real`.  Feel free to post that as your own answer.

Comment: [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152377/71256)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 70 bytes

```
x=>(y=(x+'').slice(2),p=(a,b)=>b?a%b?p(b,a%b):a/b:0,p(10**y.length,y))
```

If we can change input type to a string, then it may save 5 bytes.

Comment: This won't work for numbers >= 10.

Comment: @Shaggy Is supporting numbers > 1 needed?

Comment: Yes, it should work for any rational number (ignoring round-off error).

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes

```apl
{1e¯9>t←1|⍵:⍵⋄∇÷t}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@/2jD10HpLu5JHbRMMax71brUC4kfdLY862g9vL6n9nwYUx6@ESwEIyoByBgp6hgp6Rgp6xgp6Jgp6pgp6Zgp65gp6Fgp6lgqGCsZ6hiZgtY/6pgJVl@kcWpF2aEUZlwLXfwA)

## APL NARS, 18 chars

-1 byte thanks to Uriel
test

```apl
f←{1e¯9>t←1|⍵:⍵⋄∇÷t}
v←0 .1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9 1 3.14
⎕←v,¨f¨v
  0 0  0.1 10  0.2 5  0.3 3  0.4 2  0.5 2  0.6 2  0.7 3  0.8 4  0.9 9  1 1  3.14 7
```

Comment: `⍵-⌊⍵` → `1|⍵` for one byte

Comment: @Uriel thank you... So the bytes are as the J solution

Answer (score 1):

## Smalltalk, 33 bytes

```
[(y:=x\\1)>0]whileTrue:[x:=1/y].x
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ç▄é⌠á◙àù
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=87dc82f4a00a8597&i=0%2F1%0A1%2F10%0A2%2F10%0A3%2F10%0A4%2F10%0A5%2F10%0A6%2F10%0A7%2F10%0A8%2F10%0A9%2F10%0A10%2F10%0A314%2F100%0A628%2F100&a=1&m=2)

"Bonus points" for no precision errors.  No floating point arithmetic used.  This (finally) makes use of stax's built-in rational type.